# Position a legend in a plot at a specified location, and only fallback to "best" if it is overlapping with smth (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that you can use `ax.legend(loc='best')` to tell matplotlib to find the location with the least overlap to place the legend in my plot. However, in my plots there are often several locations that have no overlap, but by using the "best" option the legends are put in different locations on different plots (I assume the ones most "far away" from any data points). I don't like this unnecessary inconsistency between the plots. I would like to have my legends always at `ax.legend(loc='lower right')`, and only fall back to `ax.legend(loc='best')` if the legend is actually overlapping with data points ... is there a a way this can be done generically?

Comment: You can reimplement what matplotlib does internally, i.e. do a *badness* ranking of all possible 9 positions, and then decide for yourself which *badness* value is large enough to move the legend elsewhere. Pretty cumbersome though.

Comment: Another option could be to make the legend draggable. Always set it at the lower right and drag it if needed.  `leg = ax.legend(); leg.set_draggable(True)`